# Plain JavaScript or BackboneJS Approach for Alphabet Filters

Tags: backbone.js, filter

In your opinion, is it best to go overboard with BackboneJS and use templates as much as possible or adding elements like an Alphabet Filter should simply be done with JavaScript.

Clarification: Alphabet Filter to filter results [a], [b], [c] etc to get results starting with a, b, c etc

Answer (score 0):

Plain JavaScript would be my answer on 1999.

On 2013, is there a functionality that do you like to implement on JavaScript without MVC(in this case Backbone.js)?

Alphabet filters with plain JavaSript equals to reinvent the wheel, with Backbone is just to filter a collection.

I do not have doubts man, use Backbone.js

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted quite a long time ago, but there is now an open source vanilla JavaScript plugin available that will alphabetically filter any HTML list with alphabetical navigation

It's called [AlphaListNav.js](https://elliottprogrammer.github.io/alphaListNav.js/)

Just output your HTML list:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Eggplant</li>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Carrots</li>
  <li>Blueberries</li>  
</ul>
```

Add the CSS in the `<head>` of your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alphaListNav.css">
```

Add the JavaScript file just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="alphaListNav.js"></script>
```

And then Initialize the AlphaListNav library on your list by passing it the id of your list. Like so:

```
<script>
    new AlphaListNav('myList');
</script>
```

It has all kinds of different options for customizing the behavior you may want:

For example:

```
<script>
  new AlphaListNav('myList', {
    initLetter: 'A',
    includeAll: false,
    includeNums: false,
    removeDisabled: true,
    //and many other options available..
  });
</script>
```

The GitHub project is [here](https://github.com/elliottprogrammer/alphaListNav.js)

And a CodePen example is [here](https://codepen.io/melliatto/pen/vwWjjj)

The AlphaListNav.js website & documentation is [here](https://elliottprogrammer.github.io/alphaListNav.js/)